# Installing Qiskit Error: Building wheel failed!

Tags: qiskit

I have been trying to install Qiskit in a virtual Python environment via pip through Miniconda command prompt on Windows 10. The issue is with using Microsoft Visual Studio tools such cl, nmake, etc. The command prompt cannot find them. However, I followed the Qiskit's installation instructions and I have installed Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributor 2015.

I tried to find to add Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributor 2015 as a path variable but couldnt find its location (not in C:/programfiles (x64)/Microsoft Visual Studio).

Any help is greatly appreciated!!!!

[image: Screenshot of the error]

Comment: What version of python are you running in your virtual env?

Comment: Welcome to Quantum Computing SE! I take it that [these](https://qiskit.org/documentation/install.html) are the installation instructions you're referring to? (just to check so I can [edit] the link in for completeness)

Comment: I am using Python 3.8.1 and am indeed using those instructions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try installing using

> pip install wheel

[Refer here.](https://pythonwheels.com/)

Wheels are the new standard of Python distribution and are intended to replace eggs. Support is offered in pip >= 1.4 and setuptools >= 0.8.

Comment: And also do install Cmake and specify environmental variable,for C compiler which is located in control panel, which inturn would help you.